# "Try to open" VS "Try to get it open"

Tags: grammar

> He tried to open the door.
>
> He tried to get the door open.

As a basic learner I use the second sentence only in the sense of **causative verbs**. Can it be used in some other sense?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to know if the two sentences have different meanings? They *might* mean the same thing, or the second sentence *might* mean that he tried to get *someone else* to open the door rather than attempting it himself.

Comment: Please explain all the points.

Comment: Nobody can answer your question without understanding what it is that you're asking.

Comment: @JasonBassford I am sorry sir, can they mean the same?

Comment: As I said, they *might* mean the same thing. (Or they might not.) It depends on the context.

Comment: @JasonBassford could you give some examples when they both are meaning the same